# Multiply three table in DJANGO without raw_sql

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I have three models in Django that we could schematize like this :

```
class A(models.Model):
   b = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class B(models.Model):
   c = models.ForeignKey(C, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class C(models.Model):
   data = models.IntegerField()
```

My aim is to make a query equivalent to : select * from A, B, C where a.b=b.id and b.c=c.id;

My question is : Is there a way to make this query without using raw sql ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: Are you sure that this is the correct logic as a.b would return a class B object while b.id would return an integer and comparing them would return an error.

Comment: Yes **Zhivko Zaikov**, because "select * from A, B, C where a.b=b.id and b.c=c.id;" is an sql command